# К какому жанру и роду литературы относится детская раскраска?

Tags: литературоведение

К какому жанру и роду литературы относится детская раскраска? Или невозможно отнести?

Смотрела по аналогии про **газету**, которая определяется в Вики как печатное периодическое издание. Кроме него, относится к печатному периодическому изданию журнал, календарь, справочник.

Про раскраску не получилось найти. С одной стороны, она вроде газеты, журнала. Но, если в раскраске есть сюжет, который от начала до конца проводится, даются попутные задания?.. Просто формой, например, рассказа раскраску не назовешь – если изъять голый текст, без иллюстраций, заданий, он рассыплется, будет неполноценным, нелогичным, непоследовательным: останется много невосполнимых без картинок и заданий смысловых лакун. Может, есть в литературоведении понятие о каких-нибудь эклектичных жанрах?

- Гадать можно, но не хочется. Есть ли факты по этому вопросу?

Comment: Интерактивный детский комикс?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуем разобраться в терминологии.

Раскраска — это книга или страница с контурными картинками для раскрашивания.

Но картинки сами по себе — это не текст, к литературе не относятся (к литературе относятся только тексты). Если у вас сочетание текста с картинками для раскрашивания, то его классификация в мире литературы определается именно текстом. Это может быть рассказ, или учебное пособие, или какой-то смешанный вид (рассказ с заданиями), но с точки зрения рода и жанра все равно определяющим является текст. Причем понятия рода и жанра используются только по отношению к художественной литературе, а раскраска может относиться и к учебной.